# undefined function call inside class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am using angular2 with typescript and i have defined a class

```
export class Example{

 //.../

   const self: all = this;
   functionToCall(){
      //.. Do somerthing
   }

   mainFunctionCall(){
      somepromise.then(x => self.functionToCall('url/'+ x.name ) )
   }
}
```

But it keeps throwing error about functionToCall being undefined.

Im quite new to typescript/angular@

is there any rule that prevents this to be correct? Or what is the correct way to invoke method of class inside another method ?

Comment: Why not just use the `this` keyword without pointing `self` to it? The type-casting of `all` could be messing it up.

Comment: this keyword would be pointing to the scope of method , so it would be looking for functionCall method inside mainFunctionCall  and that would result in error

Comment: That is not the case with js "classes". Or even if this were an object, `this` would refer to `Example` and it will work as desired.

Comment: In TS A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.

Comment: Updated question , its propably the problem of this keyword in promises

Comment: Have you tried to just use `this`? Lambdas capture the this keyword of outer lexical scopes.

Comment: @TamasHegedus yes i did , i updated question for more detail , i am actually using promises isnide method and calling functionToCall() inside then()

Comment: @trolkura yes I saw that. You can use `this` there.

Comment: @TamasHegedus i thought this does not work well this promises.. anyway its the same result with this .. complaining about function being undefined

Comment: Then please show us some code that compiles and reproduces the issue since it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

No need for such a hack here, since lambda functions capture the `this` reference of the outer scope. You can just simply write:

```
const somepromise = Promise.resolve({name:"noone"});

class Example {

    functionToCall(x : string) {
        console.log(x);
    }

    mainFunctionCall() {
        somepromise.then(x => this.functionToCall('url/'+ x.name ) )
    }
}

(new Example()).mainFunctionCall();
```

**Edit** Code snippet updated to include all details. Can be run in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html).